# Will this 'ac wifi' adapter improve my speeds compared to the one I own, on a 'n wifi' router?

Tags: router, compatibility, wifi-configuration, wireless-adapter

I've been using [this](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN727N.html#overview) 'n wifi' adapter for some time now, but it only supports 2.4ghz and up to 150Mbps. Since my 'n wifi' router supports speeds up to 300Mbps and has both 2.4ghz and 5ghz capabilities (and as a technician showed me with his wifi adapter), I should be able to improve my speeds quite a bit using a newer adapter.

My router is supplied when subscribing for internet in my country (Telenet for Belgians). And since it doesn't use ADSL but coax cables if i'm not mistaken, it's pretty hard (impossible?) to upgrade it yourself. They do replace older versions every few years, so I can expect 'ac wifi' at some point.

I looked for possible adapters, and [this](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T2UH.html) one has very good reviews. It has ac wifi, which I know i can't use yet, but that way its future-proof if the router gets upgraded.

So my concern is: What will happen in my case, since the router only supports up to 'n wifi'? will I even be able to use 5ghz? If not, that means it will use 2.4ghz which only has a maximum of 150Mbps.

Oh and if this is relevant: I use windows 7 (64 bit).

Comment: If the wifi adapter I linked turns out not to be a good choice, am I better of buying [this](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-11_TL-WDN4200.html#overview) one? It lacks ac wifi but supports 5ghz n wifi at 450Mbps.

Comment: why do you need ac wifi? Do you have an internal network and devices sharing files between them? If no, your Internet connection should have a limit on 8-16Mbps so the standard G (54Mbps) is well enough if you are concerned only on internet speed

Comment: I don't need it yet, but I tought it would be a good idea to buy something that is future-proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to its specifications, that adapter supports both 2.4 and 5 GHz frequencies and a, b, g, n and ac wireless networking standards. If your router is also dual-band and supports the n standard, the two devices should be able to communicate over it. However, the specifications of the adapter say that it supports up to 150 Mbps over the n standard, so you won't see any speed improvements until you upgrade your router.

Note that the n standard can be used in 2.4 and the 5 GHz frequencies and both are supported with the adapter you are considering buying, but different variables affect the transmit speed and that adapter is limited at 150 Mbps.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. It's just that I don't really understand how to interpret the different specifications it has. It says: "802.11ac, 3 times faster than wireless N speeds. With 433Mbps wireless speeds over the crystal clear 5GHz band". That sounds like unless you can actually use 802.11ac, it will not be 3 times faster, and so the maximum for me will still be the theoretical 150Mbps.

Comment: I have expanded the answer. You need both devices to support a certain standard in order to be able to establish a connection using that standard.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One last thing: could you confirm that the adapter I linked to in my separate comment is better suited for me? I'm pretty sure with that one I should have a theoretical limit of 300 Mbps.

Comment: Yes, it seems that that one is faster on the n standard. The theoretical speed limits usually cannot be achieved in practice. It's best to try and keep the option to return the adapter if it does not fulfill your needs.